# php FOR not work

Tags: php, xml

this my code. It create xml file from mysql..

my problem:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($str_exp1); $i++) // HERE 
{
  $str_exp2 = explode(",", $str_exp1[$i]);

  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $str_exp2[0]);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $str_exp2[1]);  

}
```

for not show the all data... it only show me latest one data.. i cant find where is there problem..

P.S. Sorry for my english

0

```
$doc =  new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->createElement("marker");
$parnode = $doc->appendchild($node);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersline");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{ 
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  while ($mar = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $node = $doc->createElement("line");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("id_line", $mar['id_line']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("color", $mar['colour']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("width", $mar['width']);

    $node = $doc->createElement("point");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

    $str_exp1 = explode(";", $mar['coordinats']);

    for($i=0; $i<count($str_exp1); $i++) // HERE 
    {
      $str_exp2 = explode(",", $str_exp1[$i]);

      $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $str_exp2[0]);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $str_exp2[1]);  

    }


  }
  $xmlfile = $doc->saveXML();
  echo $xmlfile;
}
else
{
  echo "<p>Ëèíèé íå îáíàðóæåíî!</p>";
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the relevant XML file, it's not easy to tell what's going wrong, but as a guess are you intentionally mis-spelling "coordinates" in the $str_exp1 = explode(";", $mar['coordinats']); line?

Comment: XML working good. i have not problem with xml..   http://nn-gis.com/map/line.php this my xml output..  my problem. For must give me 4 latlong coordinates but it gives me only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set multiple values to the same node. So you are always overwriting the attribute values with the latest lat/long value.

Instead you need to add a new element per each lat/long pair because XML elements do not have duplicate attributes.

Some example code based on your question, as you can see I introduce some functions to keep things more modular:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usersline");

if (!$result || !count($result)) {
    echo "<p>Ëèíèé íå îáíàðóæåíî!</p>";
    return;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$doc->loadXML('<marker/>');
$marker = $doc->documentElement;

foreach ($result as $mar) {

    $line = $doc->createElement('line');
    $attributes = array_map_array(['id_line', 'colour' => 'color', 'width'], $mar);
    element_add_attributes($line, $attributes);
    foreach (coordinates_to_array($mar['coordinats']) as $latlong) {
        $point = $doc->createElement('point');            
        element_add_attributes($point, $latlong);
        $line->appendChild($point);
    }

    $marker->appendChild($line);

}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();


function element_add_attributes(DOMElement $element, array $attributes)
{
    foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
        if (!is_string($name)) continue;
        $element->setAttribute($name, $value);
    }
}

function array_map_array(array $map, array $array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($map as $alias => $name) {
        $source = is_string($alias) ? $alias : $name;
        $result[$name] = $array[$source];
    }
    return $result;
}

function coordinates_to_array($coordinates)
{
    $result = array();
    $coordinatePairs = explode(";", $coordinates);

    foreach ($coordinatePairs as $coordinatePair) {
        list($pair['lat'], $pair['lng']) = explode(',', $coordinatePair, 2) + ['', ''];
        $result[] = $pair;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I hope this example is helpful and shows you some ways how you can put a problem apart so that your code becomes more easy and more stable.

---

To make use of `$db->query(...)` first define a class that has the `query` method:

```
class DB {
    public function query($sql) {
        $dbhandle = mysql_query($sql);
        $result  = array();

        while ($mar = mysql_fetch_array($dbhandle)) 
            $result[] = $mar
        ;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate it:

```
$db = new DB();
```

You can then use the code above for that part.

For the problem with the PHP 5.4 array notation for example in this line:

```
$attributes = array_map_array(['id_line', 'colour' => 'color', 'width'], $mar);
```

First of all extract the array out of it:

```
$mapping    = ['id_line', 'colour' => 'color', 'width'];
$attributes = array_map_array($mapping, $mar);
```

Then define the array with the `array(` and `)` notation instead of `[` and `]`:

```
$mapping    = array('id_line', 'colour' => 'color', 'width');
$attributes = array_map_array($mapping, $mar);
```

Do so as well in other places, e.g.

```
['', '']
```

becomes

```
array('', '')
```

and similar.

Comment: thanks for answer.. Thanks for help...  it gives me error.. cant solve it.. :(  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/content/78/9527178/html/map/line.php on line 16

Comment: The example code is written in PHP version 5.4. You are not using that PHP 5.4 version. You can learn more about the `[` character in PHP 5.4 here: http://php.net/array - to get such errors away, change those parts into *your* PHP version - whichever PHP version you are using. Should be trivial, probably `array(`.

Comment: thanks for answer. i did it.. but dont understand this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /// i didnt see there mysql query.. ((

Comment: @brio, the `$db` object is exemplary (e.g. PDO), you use the `mysql_*` functions (which I do not because they are outdated). It's just some preference. Also if you run into errors, we have a reference online here on site for common errors (like the last one): [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456).

Comment: soory.. its so hard for me((.. i dont understand it((.. please can your help with php version < 5.4.. I could not adjust php 5.3:(

Comment: @brio: Just put your querying in there and instead of the foreach take your while loop. I just don't have that so I could mock the code.  Also you find an edit with some hints for your PHP version.

Comment: broooooo thanks sooo much!!!! thnk you...  array_map_array()  here must be array_map ))..  all is good! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
$str_exp1 = explode(";", $mar['coordinats']);

$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $str_exp1[0]);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $str_exp1[1]);
```

Comment: not working(( give s error: Line Number 2, Column 1:<b>Warning</b>:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in <b>/home/content/78/9527178/html/map/line.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
^

Comment: It's just a warning. It happens when your string is empty. You can ignore it or disable error reporting.

Comment: i know it. )) bu my string is not empty..it must show me data. if i disable error reporting xml working but lat and long data now showing..